# View local development server on USB-connected iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, safari-web-inspector

I have my OS X development laptop hooked up to the net via an iPhone 5 connected with USB (Personal Hotspot). With a web server running locally for my development work, can I load pages from this server on my iPhone and then inspect them with Safari's Web Inspector? I have tried 127.0.0.1 and my connected IP public address but no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to do this - it just required a bit of investigation as to how the networking is arranged when using an iPhone via USB with Personal Hotspot. There are two steps:

Firstly, using USB, the USB port is setup as a network interface. The precise (and technical) details can be seen with `ifconfig` however what you need to know is *what IP address is used for the USB interface*.

Go to `Network Preferences` and select the `iPhone USB` on the left hand side. You will see a message like *iPhone USB is currently active and has the IP address 172.20.10.2*. Note that this is not the publicly available IP address, it is the network interface on the Mac. This is the ip address you need to type into the browser on your iPhone to see your local development server.

Secondly, you need to make sure that your local development server is serving the USB interface. This will obviously vary depending on your server but typically there will be a `HOST` parameter that directs the server to bind to that IP address. Again, use the IP address you found above to instruct the web server to serve pages on that IP.

Comment: Thank you for this. Counter-intuitive, because the message suggests the IP address is the address of the device, not the host... but it does work for opening connections on the host from the device.

Comment: This appears to only work with one iOS device at a time when connected via USB. Looking for a workaround or solution to enable multiple devices.

Comment: Update: Figured it out. In more recent versions of macOS, you will find 'iPhone USB' or 'iPad USB' in the list at System Settings → Sharing → Internet Sharing. After enabling devices and enabling Internet Sharing, you might have to unplug and re-plug the USB cable(s) to the device(s) for it to take effect.